# S3 serving mpeg-dash, will load the manifest but CORS fails on the packages

Tags: amazon-s3, mpeg-dash

I've been using S3 to serve MPEG-Dash videos and it's been working fine.

I've made some changes to the video processing jobs, but they're still publishing to the same place but now I'm getting the strange problem where the manifest (in the same folder) loads fine, but I get the following error:

> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'https://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

S3 is configured with the following rule

```
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>https://localhost:3000</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>DELETE</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
```

and has never been a problem before.

The urls load fine in the browser, so they are valid.

I'm not getting any responses when I look in debug tool there is no response but it's status code 403

Comment: You have rule for HTTP `<AllowedOrigin>http://localhost:3000</AllowedOrigin>` but accessing page via HTTPS as I see in the CORS error.

Comment: Thanks I have https as well I should have shown that instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was a mis-configured local testing proxy server